# How do I get list of installed apps Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

How do I get list of installed apps Android Studio?

Comment: "I was told to get a list of all apps installed on the device without using PackageManager" - That's a ridiculous restriction. What's the point of that?

Comment: Are you sue that you are prohibited to use `getPackageManager()`? And, are you asked to do it for rooted devices only?

Comment: Sorry..I got it wrong ..It was not without using but instead by creating a new class and inheriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Without using PackageManager here is what you can get

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

and this only shows application that are preinstalled or can run the ACTION_MAIN Intent type.

Hope it helps.